# unity OnColliderEnter() のオブジェクトの管理について

Tags: unity3d

自分は今までOnColliderEnter()を”スクリプトがアタッチされているオブジェクト”が”その他の何か”に接触した時の挙動に使っていましたが、例えば、ControllerにOnColliderEnter()をアタッチして、”（スクリプトがアタッチされていない）別のオブジェクト”と”（スクリプトがアタッチされていない）さらに別のオブジェクト”が接触する判定って取れたりしますか？

質問がわかりにくくてすみません・・・。

何がしたいかというと、全てControllerのクラスで管理したいときに他オブジェクトのOnColliderEnter()の処理もできるのかどうかが知りたいのです。

Answer (score 1):

直接取ることはできません。
（もちろんColliderを使わずに衝突判定を自分で実装すればできますが、それは意図する所と違いますよね？）

なので、Controllerに衝突時のロジックを書くのであれば、
1. Controller側に衝突時のロジックを書く(仮にHandleCollisions()とします)
2. Colliderがアタッチされた、実際に衝突するGameObjectのOnColliderEnter()で、Controller::HandleCollisions()を呼び出す
とする必要があります。